# Why GregorianCalendar returns 0 instead of MONTH?

Tags: java

I have a problem with creating dates.

```
Calendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
int leto = randBetween(2001, 2020);
gc.set(GregorianCalendar.YEAR, leto);
int dan= randBetween(1, gc.getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
gc.set(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, dan);
//   System.out.println(gc.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR) + "-" +
//     gc.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) + "-" +
//     gc.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

public static int randBetween(int start, int end) {
  return start + (int)Math.round(Math.random() * (end - start));
}
```

I have a function for generating a date but in this function there are a lot of failures. I get many dates where the MONTH value is not set.

```
31,6,2004 1,7,2004
23,0,2013 24,0,2013
19,0,2008 20,0,2008 
31,9,2014 31,9,2014
```

But I don't know why this happens?

Comment: What fails?  What exactly is going wrong?  Is the program crashing, or are you just getting unexpected results?  How do the actual results vary from the expected results?

Comment: 31.6 didnt exsist i think :( and 20.0 didnt exisits same

Comment: Months in Java are 0-based.  It looks like you have July 31st, August 1st, January 23rd, etc.

Comment: I recommend using JodaTime for dates.  I wrestled with GregorianCalendar for years until I finally got smart and switched.

Comment: rgettman you are legend .D

Answer (score 3):

This code is not ‘failing’, it is however not giving the expected result.

The dates that you are seeing are:

```
23,0,2013  -- 23rd of January, 2013.
31,6,2013  -- 31st of July, 2013.
```

That is, `month` is not 1-based, unlike day, it is 0-based.

Rest assured, this is fairly common mistake with the Java Date API, and probably the only person who thinks that is is logical is the person who came up with this API, and probably not even them anymore…